# Unit testing Controllers with Mockito

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, scalatest, playframework-2.3

I am using **ScalaTest** and **Mockito** to unit test application controllers.

My Controller and its unit test is written as follows

Controller -

```
class UserCRUDController(userCRUDService :UserCRUDService) extends Controller {
  def create() = Action.async(parse.anyContent) {
    request =>
      val result = userCRUDService.create
      val timeOut = Promise.timeout("timed out", 2.second)
      Future.firstCompletedOf(Seq(result, timeOut)).map {
        case "timed out" => InternalServerError(
          Json.obj("ok" -> "1", "message" -> "Request Timed Out!!!")
        )
        case status: JsObject => Ok(status)
      }
  }
}
```

Controller Unit Test -

```
class UserCRUDControllerTest extends FunSpec with Matchers with MockitoSugar {

  describe("UserCRUD controller") {

    describe("Create") {
      it("should be timed out after 2 seconds") {
        val mockUserCRUDService = mock[UserCRUDService]
        val controller = new UserCRUDController(mockUserCRUDService)
        val fakeRequest = FakeRequest("POST", routes.UserCRUDControllerInstance.create().toString)
        val timedOutResponse = Future {
          Thread.sleep(3000)
          Json.obj("test" -> "timed out")
        }

        when(mockUserCRUDService.create).thenReturn(timedOutResponse)

        val result = controller.create()(fakeRequest)

        status(result) should be(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
        contentAsJson(result) should be(
          Json.obj("ok" -> "1", "message" -> "Request Timed Out!!!")
        )
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But i am getting following error while running the test

```
[info] UserCRUDControllerTest:
[info] UserCRUD controller
[info]   Create
[info]   - should be timed out after 2 seconds *** FAILED ***
[info]     java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no started application
[info]     at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
[info]     at play.api.Play$$anonfun$current$1.apply(Play.scala:71)
[info]     at play.api.Play$$anonfun$current$1.apply(Play.scala:71)
[info]     at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
[info]     at play.api.Play$.current(Play.scala:71)
[info]     at play.api.libs.concurrent.Promise$.timeout(Promise.scala:50)
[info]     at play.api.libs.concurrent.Promise$.timeout(Promise.scala:37)
[info]     at controllers.UserCRUDController$$anonfun$create$1.apply(UserCRUDController.scala:15)
[info]     at controllers.UserCRUDController$$anonfun$create$1.apply(UserCRUDController.scala:13)
[info]     at play.api.mvc.Action$.invokeBlock(Action.scala:556)
[info]     ...
```

This gets solved when I wrap the test within `running(FakeApplication())` but throws Exception otherwise.

> Do I need to run a fake application instance always when I use mocks
>   in unit test?